# GTM & contact form 7 - gtm.formSubmit not firing

Tags: google-tag-manager

On a single-page website with 3 forms (contact form 7 from wordpress), when one of these forms is submitted, I send a data layer event to Google Tag Manager:

```
on_sent_ok: "dataLayer.push({'event':'formSubmit'});"
```

In GTM i created a custom event trigger which fires when it gets the event "formSubmit". To sepearte the 3 forms from each other and use a sepearte tag for every form i filter the trigger with the id of the form:

[image]

Now the event trigger cant trigger because gtm.formSubmit is not fireing. I just get the formSubmit event and no gtm.FormSubmit. 
[image]

Any idea how i can get a separate trigger for all the 3 forms?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your tags and triggers as well?

Comment: On the third one you can see that the active element is the input element rather than the form it is in..

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help. Now i think i got closer to the problem. As soon as i use all event-triggers as "customized" in GTM the "gtm.formSubmit" is not firing on all forms. But when i leave one trigger with an event-type "send form" the gtm-formSubmit is firing on all forms working? Has this anything to do with this data layers?

Comment: The gtm.formSubmit is from a builtin listener that only runs when you have a tag that uses the forms triggers. If it can handle all your cases then you can just use it. If not, you need your own push, but you need to fix it to use a variable that finds the id of the form which is not always the current element but should always be an ancestor of the current element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a different trigger for every form i now use a different dataLayer.push event for all of these forms:

```
on_sent_ok: "dataLayer.push({'event':'form1Submit'});"
on_sent_ok: "dataLayer.push({'event':'form2Submit'});"
on_sent_ok: "dataLayer.push({'event':'form3Submit'});"
```

So now i dont need to filter the form id in GTM i can just trigger when one of these events is firing. This works perfectly, the event is firing when contact form 7 is submited correctly and its not triggering when the submit button is clicked.
[image]