# GTM & Contact Form 7 - goals not being logged

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, contact-form-7

Much the same as [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957117/gtm-contact-form-7-gtm-formsubmit-not-firing), I've got a WordPress website with multiple forms often on the same page. My forms are created using Contact Form 7.

For example, when the 'Request a Call' form is completed, a data layer is sent using:

`on_sent_ok: "dataLayer.push({'event':'formSubmit-RequestACall'});"`

In GTM, I have a custom trigger set up as follows:

[image: Request Call GTM Trigger]

Here are the Tag settings:

[image]

Meanwhile, over in GA, I've set up the following Goal:

[image: Request Call GA Goal]

However, if I submit the request a call form and look at Real-Time goal completions in GA, nothing is showing. Is anyone able to advise where I'm going wrong please?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** My Preview summary says the tag isn't firing. There's one tag firing, which is the one I'm using to measure overall traffic.

The DataLayer feedback is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Could you also attach printscreen showing how you set up a tag in GTM? Maybe you forget about adding a tag to send event to GA (because setting up a trigger without a tag is not enough)

Comment: @JacekSzymański Thanks for your reply. I've amended my post - please see above. It's the second image.

Comment: First: change "Action" field in tag and/or in goal details. Cause in tag you named it: "Submit", in goal settings you called it: "sent" ;) both should be exactly the same. {{Form Event}} is your's custom variable? Are you sure that "Form event" value is equal to "formSubmit-RequestACall" ? I think you should change {{Form Event}} to {{Event}} if u're expecting "forumsubmit-RequestACall" value in label.

Comment: @JacekSzymański Sorry, I changed it since I posted the two original screenshots. It is consistently saying 'Submit'.

Comment: Did you try to change {{Form Event}} just to {{Event}} in label field? I think there's a problem. Or try to enable "preview mode" and check what values are stored in {{Form Event}} after sending a form on site.

Comment: @JacekSzymański Just tried this but unfortunately it hasn't worked.

Comment: @JacekSzymański I've just seen your comment update - when I click preview it doesn't do anything other than throw me back to the Overview tab in GTM. I'm in a test environment at the moment - I don't know if that makes a difference?

Comment: Send form for a test and check in Google Analytics panel in: "Real-Time / Events" section event parameters (especially "label"). I hope events are collecting in "Real-time" ?

Comment: @JacekSzymański Sorry, my preview function wasn't working because of a script blocker. I've added the results to the end of the original post. Basically, it isn't firing.

Comment: Ok, so simply type this JS line (with GTM preview mode on): `dataLayer.push({'event':'formSubmit-RequestACall'});` in console (developers tools in browser). Does GTM recognize, collect and show new event in debug window? It should.

Comment: I went out for a walk, came back, sat down and finally cracked this! I'll post my settings here to save some other poor soul the pain. Just to say @JacekSzymański thank you - you've been a real help and I'm massively grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Crikey! I've finally got to grips with it. In the hope of saving someone else the best part of a day, here are my settings, which work for me.

**dataLayer.push (under 'Additional Settings' in Contact Form 7)**

`on_sent_ok: "dataLayer.push({'event':'formSubmit-RequestACall'});"`

**Google Tag Manager - Trigger**

[image]

**Google Tag Manager - Tag**

[image]

**Google Analytics - Goal**

[image]

The verification as you can see in the last photo says it would expect 0% conversion based on last 7 days data. This is despite the goal registering in the Real-Time (last 30 mins) data, so I expect it needs 24 hours to register the goal properly.

No variable settings necessary. I now just need to repeat for the other forms, changing the event name for each (i.e. instead of `formSubmit-RequestACall`) to something unique.

Good luck!